# How to install Bootstrap Studio on Manjaro-Linux

Tags: software-installation, manjaro, aur

What do I have to do to install Bootstrap Studio on my Manjaro-Linux System?

I downloaded the 64-bit Version for any linux distribution [here](https://www.bootstrapstudio.io/download/), but I dont know what to do.

There is a package in AUR, but it is deprecated. You can find it [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/bootstrap-studio/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the .tar.gz of their website, [here](https://bootstrapstudio.io/download).

Would look like this:

```
wget "https://bootstrapstudio.io/releases/desktop/4/Bootstrap%20Studio%204%20(64bit).tar.gz"
tar -xzvf 'Bootstrap Studio 4 (64bit).tar.gz'
```

If you want to see it works, just run: `./Bootstrap\ Studio/Bootstrap\ Studio`

Best thing to do is move this directory to `/opt` and make a symbolic link towards `/usr/bin` of `'Bootstrap Studio'`

```
sudo cp -r ./Bootstrap\ Studio /opt/Bootstrap\ Studio
sudo ln -s /opt/Bootstrap\ Studio/Bootstrap\ Studio /usr/bin/bootstrapstudio
```

Not sure how you set this up to function as a desktop application.. but I am sure you can figure that out.

Comment: Thanks to your tutorial and this [guide](https://www.maketecheasier.com/create-desktop-file-linux/) it was very easy to get it running! Thank you!

Comment: @Andi glad it worked out.